# JSch SFTP transfer changes encoding

Tags: java, utf-8, character-encoding, sftp, jsch

I am using JSch to transfer an UTF-8 encoded XML File from a Windows machine running Bitvise SSH Server to a local directory on my linux machine (Ubuntu) using the following code:

```
// Open JSch session
JSch jsch = new JSch();
session = jsch.getSession("username", "host", 22);
session.setPassword("password");
session.setConfig("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
session.setTimeout(5 * 60 * 1000);
session.connect();

// Open SFTP Connection
ChannelSftp sftpChannel = (ChannelSftp)session.openChannel("sftp");
sftpChannel.connect();

// Download the XML File to a local directory
byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
final BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(sftpChannel.get("file.xml", new DeliveryProgressMonitor()));
final BufferedOutputStream bos = new BufferedOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(targetFile));
int readCount = -1;

while( (readCount = bis.read(buffer)) > 0) {
    bos.write(buffer, 0, readCount);
}

// Closing + Cleanup of resources
```

I verified that the file being retrieved is stored in UTF-8 without BOM on the Server, having characters like `äöü` correctly encoded.

After transferring the file using the code above the file is still in UTF-8 encoding on the target machine (`file -bi` outputs `application/xml; charset=utf-8`), however viewing the contents of the file I can see that `äöü` are no longer readable and have been converted to character sequences like `Ã¼`.

The same problem also occurs with the example program from

http://www.jcraft.com/jsch/examples/Sftp.java.html

as well as when using the scp command line.

Using the same Java code to transfer the file to my development machine running Windows 10 keeps the file intact.

How can I make sure that the encoding stays intact, regardless of the Operating system used on the client machine?

Comment: In all likelihood, everything is working fine;  it is the tool you are using to view the file on the destination machine that is the problem.  `Ã¼` is what you see when you treat a UTF-8 sequence as if it's ISO 8859-1 (or Windows-1252).  How are you viewing the contents of the received file?

Comment: Thanks VGR, that was actually the problem. Turns out my XML-Parser vi was using latin1 encoding and my xml-parser was complaining about newlines within the data and not about the encoding itself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As pointed out by VGR in a comment above the transfer was working fine, it was just the editor using the wrong encoding to open the file